# Scale/transition image to size of parent with css

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations

I want to expand an image to the size of its parent div with a css transition. Here are the parameters:

- the image should expand from center
- the image should fill the entire rectangular div
- the solution should not use javascript/jquery

My current hack-imation looks unprofessional and 'square-y'..

Markup:

```
<div class="col info contain">
                <!-- <h4>Info Block One</h4> -->
                <p><img alt="blob" class="avatar-wobble imageBg" width="180" height="200" src="static/991100.jpg"></p>
                <p class="filler991100"></p>
                <p><img alt="blob" class="imageTop image img-circle" width="60" height="60" src="static/hairface.jpg"></p>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .contain {
    position: relative;
}

.img-circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    border:1px solid black;
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.info:hover .img-circle {
    transform: translate3d(0px, -150px, 0px)
        scale(0.7);
}


.image {
    position: absolute;
}

.imageBg {
    z-index: 0;
}

.imageTop {
    z-index: 1;
    top:150px;
    left:75px;
}

.filler991100 {
    display: block;
    background: #991100;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.info:hover .filler991100{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius:0;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    background: #991100;
}
```

You can see that my hack uses a class that has the same color as my image, to make it appear like the image is growing to the rectangular shape of its parent div. I used an image here because its shape is irregular. Here's what it currently looks like:

https://youtu.be/45VNx7JbRc4

Here's what I'm after:

https://youtu.be/QwjPQ5G2W0o

Comment: Hard to understand exactly what you're asking. You mention expanding an image to fill a div, but your example has two images and a div, and neither image expands. What is the difference between what we see if we run your code and what you want to see? Also, please consider editing your post to put your code in a snippet, and to include actual (non-broken) images in your code. You can use a placeholder service like http://placehold.it if you need to.

Comment: here's the goal: https://youtu.be/QwjPQ5G2W0o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above - it's hard to uderstand what exactly do you want to achieve. If what you want is to have some picture, and then you want some other picture to transition from it's center on hover, this may help:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.contain {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.avatar-wobble{
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/200x200);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.avatar-wobble::after {
  content: '';
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200);
  background-position: center center;
  position: absolute;
  height: 200%;
  width: 200%;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip-path: circle(50px at center);
}
.avatar-wobble:hover::after {
  clip-path: circle(200px at center);
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
  <div class="avatar-wobble"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: not exactly - I'm looking for a visible image - the blob - to expand from its center (in the form of a circle, not a square) to the full size of the rectangular div, like in the desired outcome video snippet I added - thx

Comment: I've modified my snippet according to your suggestions

Comment: You can add background-position:center to .avatar-wobble::after to keep the image center while resizing.

Comment: @fen1x that's almost exactly what I'm after, except that both of our shapes noticeably morph into a square before they reach the edges. The idea is for the circle/blob shape to keep growing so large that they conceivably extend past the corners of the rectangle, such that they fill the entire rectanle, and the excess is hidden. Would overflow hidden solve that? thx

Comment: @DNburtonguster it can done with `clip-path`, see my edited snippet